# Check if xml values are contained within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
var results = response.Xml.Descendants("M").Where(foo => foo.Value.Contains("john"));
```

How do I change this to be:

```
List<string> ValidUsers = new List<string>();
ValidUsers.Add("John");
ValidUsers.Add("Smurf");
var results = response.Xml.Descendants("M")
    .Where(foo => foo.Value.Contains(ValidUsers));
```

Comment: `.Where(foo => ValidUsers.Contains(foo.Value));` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("M")
　　　　.Where(foo => ValidUsers.Any(s => foo.Value.Contains(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch it (just a guess, not testet).

Not `foo.Value.Contains(ValidUsers)` but `ValidUsers.Contains(foo.Value)`.

Comment: O k a y  I  a m  s o r r y :)